# Sending HTML tags in props - react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, interpolation

I need something function or trick to allow using HTML tags in react's props, because i'm using ckeditor for form.

my code:

```
render(){
    let name = this.props.name;
    let text = this.props.description;
    console.log(text);
    return (
        <li class="collection-item avatar">
          <span class="title"> <strong> {name} </strong> </span>
          <p > {text} </p>
          <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
        </li>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) might help you.

Example from doc:

```
function createMarkup() { return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'}; };
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Always keep in mind that setting html directly can lead to XSS, so you should avoid the stuff as long as possible.